# Create a list copy having distanced duplicate elements

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list containing integers, I would like to create a copy of it such that duplicate elements are at least some distance apart. I am aware that it is necessary to have "enough" different elements and a sufficiently "long" starting list but I would like to create that copy or return a message that it is not possible (for that distance).

Here is a python "possible" implementation but sometimes this program creates an infinite loop.

```
import random

out = []
pbs = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
l = len(pbs)
step = 3

while l > 0:

    pb = random.choice(pbs)

    if pb in out:
        lastindex = out[::-1].index(pb)
        if (len(out) - lastindex) < step:
            continue
    pbs.remove(pb)
    out.append(pb)
    l += -1

print(out)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking why there is an infinite loop?

Comment: Can you add an example input and output

Comment: Instead of getting the index of the last matching number, just check if `pb in out[-step:]`. You can run into an infinite loop if `len(set(pbs)) < step` (or maybe <=).

Comment: @mkrieger1 I want to avoid the infinite loop by reordering the pbs list to have duplicate elements distanced.

Comment: Do you want the list to simply fulfill that constraint, or also to be (or at least look) random?

Comment: @tobias_k I want to fulfill the distancing constraint and a random resulting list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a generative approach, adding numbers to the result as long as they fulfill the constraints and backtracking if no such number is available. This way, you can generate all, or just a single such permutation (with `next`). The problem with this approach is that it does not check if the constraints can be satisfied at all, i.e. if no solution can be found, it can run for quite a long time for longer lists...

```
import random, collections

def scramble(lst, step):
    def backtrack(i, counts, pos):
        if not any(counts.values()):
            yield []
        for x in sorted(counts, key=lambda x: random.random()):
            if counts[x] > 0 and (not pos[x] or i - pos[x][-1] >= step):
                counts[x] -= 1
                pos[x].append(i)
                for res in backtrack(i+1, counts, pos):
                    yield [x] + res
                pos[x].pop()
                counts[x] += 1
    return backtrack(0, collections.Counter(lst), collections.defaultdict(list))


pbs = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
# ~ pbs = [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(100)]
step = 4

for x in scramble(pbs, step):
    print(x)
```

Here, `sorted(counts, key=lambda x: random.random())` means that the next number to be tested is determined randomly. Instead, you may want to use `key=lambda x: -counts[x]` for testing most-constrained numbers first, or a combination like `key=lambda x: (-counts[x], random.random())`. This will find results faster, but is less random.

---

Or using a stochastic-optimization approach, swapping pairs of elements and keeping the result if it is better then the previous one for a limited number of "generations". Again, this does not check if such a solution can be found a-priori, and other than the above, this generates only a single solution, or raises an exception if none is found.

```
def score(lst, step):
    pos = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        pos[x].append(i)
    return sum(max(0, step - (b-a)) for p in pos.values() for a, b in zip(p, p[1:]))

def scramble(lst, step, max_iter=1000):
    lst = list(lst)
    random.shuffle(lst)
    s = score(lst, step)
    for i in range(max_iter):
        lst2 = list(lst)
        a, b = random.randrange(len(lst)), random.randrange(len(lst))
        lst2[a], lst2[b] = lst2[b], lst2[a]
        s2 = score(lst2, step)
        if s2 == 0:
            return lst2
        elif s2 < s:
            lst, s = lst2, s2
    else:
        raise StopIteration(f"No result found after {max_iter} iteration")
```

Comment: Many thanks @tobias_k for these answers. I was wondering if increasing max_iter would increase the chance of fulfilling the distancing constraint, because I think that if we reach max_iter without satisfying this constraint it does not mean that the problem has no solution and perhaps a new call to the scramble procedure (with "new" random choices) could lead to a solution respecting the desired constraint.

Comment: @Clifford Exactly, the second approach is not guaranteed to find a solution, and having it run for longer (or even doing multiple random restarts, each running only shortly) might yield better results. Of course, it would be better to have a (fast) check to see if such solution exists first, not sure how that would look.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my current understanding of your problem:
(Not sure how to name the operation yet;
using 'takeEvery' as a placeholder.
Probably there is an algorithm for that somewhere.)

```
def takeEvery(list, step):
  out = []
  for pb in pbs:
    if pb in out:
      lastindex = out.index(pb)  # keeping 'out' in reverse
      if lastindex < step: continue
    out.insert(0, pb)  # insert in reverse (easier search)
  out.reverse()
  return out

pbs = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
step = 3
out = takeEvery(pbs, step)

print('Step:', step)
print('Original:', pbs)
print('Result:  ', out)
```

Comment: But this just skips the elements; I think you should instead re-schedule them and try again later, although that may fail, too.

Comment: @tobias_k Ah, ok, now I understand why the calls to random. Thought that duplicate elements closer than step should be skipped. Well, scrap that then.